# Connection between PLC and OPC server

Tags: plc, opc-ua, siemens

I have three Siemens S1200 PLC devices and one PC Station which is OPC server.
PLC 1 ethernet configuration is 172.16.100.100/255.255.255.0, PLC 2 172.16.100,101/255.255.2550, PLC 3 is 172.16.100.102/255.255.255.0 and PC Station 172.16.100.1/255.255.255.0

I would like to connect all three PLCs on the one PC station but the IP addressing is not matching. Then I set for each PLC to user router. For router address I used address of PC Station. The question is, could this work on this way? Unfortunately I don't have in the moment PC Station so I'm not able to test this.

This is how it looks network configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work if you remove the "use router"(same subnet) and only use one CP-Card in the "PC-Station". The CP-card must have the same network configuration in Windows as in this configuration, and please configure only the interface really needed. The OPC-server doesn't use this configuration for anything but the communication to the PLCs.

To transfer the "PC-Station" to a "PC" please use the context menu item "Configure PC Station Online" (right click on the "PC Station")

//PerD